# Disable clearing event logs in Keycloack

Tags: keycloak

I'm using Keycloack to protect some web application deployed on Tomcat. There is a requirement from security department to disable ability to clear login and admin events logs.I was searching the web and documentation but failed to find any info... Is it possible at all? Did anyone tried to use CSS to hide the buttons if Keycloack doesn't have such functionality? Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

- create a group for your Keycloak console administrators
- give most permissions (realm-management roles) to this group, except the role `manage-events`
- create a user account in this group for all you company Keycloak admins
- strictly reserve the principal admin account for extreme cases, in such a way that no one should use it.

That way, even administrators will not be able to clear events.

Note that you may have to play a bit with the set of permissions to add before obtaining the perfect result (and it depends on the Keycloak version), but you should be close.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try what you wrote and get back with the results

Comment: not yet. We managed to put off this configuration due there are more important things like going to production. I'll post here my results as soon as I get to the task again.